# Compose string manipulation operations in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, expression

I'm trying to remove the directory prefix from $soy:

```
a=${soy#*$PREFIX}
```

then changing slashes per dots:

```
b=${a//\//.}
```

the goal is to convert a file-path to a module path inside a program.

Anyways, is there any way to do this i **one expression using composition**?

This doesn't work :(

```
${${soy#*$PREFIX}//\//.}
```

Comment: Shell variable operators aren't cryptic enough, you feel the need to cram multiple of them in one expression?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's a whim. But it doesn't stop being interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog comment](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919#comment-349879) at Linux Journal, you can't do multiple operations in one expression.